How to Advertise IPv6 ULA Subnet?
When I first enabled IPv6 with stateless addressing, I wanted to add static addresses for LAN services (Unique Local Addresses).  I used a subnet generator to randomly select a prefix beginning with FD.
To get the clients set up with this local subnet, I found a way to Enable IPv6 Router Advertisements on Windows.
However, I prefer not to rely on Windows for this.
How would I migrate that router advertisement service to Ubuntu?

radvd is a router advertisement daemon

@sleepyhead I'll fiddle with that and see what happens.

Here's what worked.
Create a file at /etc/radvd.conf and reference conf syntax.
interface my-if-name
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        prefix fdaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::/64
        {
                AdvValidLifetime 2592000;
                AdvPreferredLifetime 604800;
        };
};

Substitute the interface name for something listed by the ip a command.  Substitute the prefix for a random value.  Then...
apt install radvd
For troubleshooting, check the /var/log/syslog file for details.  Beware if you use radvd without params it will continue running until you kill it.
To start the advertisement daemon as a service and to enable it at boot, use the commands
 systemctl start radvd
 systemctl enable radvd

